# How to convert complete android project to Cordova plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I have an android project I want to convert this whole project to **cordova** plugin but the issue I'm facing is I don't know how to configure it to start working as a plugin and not as stand alone project.

The reason why I want to convert project into plugin is that I cannot directly work with the JAVA files I want to take help in imports and suggestions provided by android studio

I have read some articles they work by directly creating Java class, which is not in my skills

[I have followed this link to create the plugin but its just a single file and not a project](https://codingsans.com/blog/cordova-android-plugin)